# Pandarallel cannot apply two transformations

Tags: python, pandas, pandarallel

I have a pandas data frame (with ~57 million rows of floats) that I want to undergo two transformations.

These are the two functions to apply the transformations:

```
def apply_feature_aggregation(df, weights, scale, shift, cores): #This runs without a problem
    t1 = time.time()
    pandarallel.initialize(nb_workers=cores, progress_bar=False) 

    new_df = df[['id']].copy()
    new_df['weight'] = df.parallel_apply(calculate_weight, axis=1, weights=weights, scale=scale, shift=shift)

    t2 = time.time()
    print(f'init weights {t2-t1}')

    return new_df


def apply_weight_scaling(df, cores): #The apply section of it only works if I click run

    pandarallel.initialize(nb_workers=cores, progress_bar=False) # initialize(36) or initialize(os.cpu_count()-1)
    t2 = time.time()
    new_df, second_min, current_max = interval_mapping_preprocessing(df, 'weight')
    t3 = time.time()

    print(f'initial mapping preprocessing finished {t3-t2}')

    new_df['weight'] = new_df.parallel_apply(apply_linear_transformation, axis=1, second_min=second_min, current_max= current_max) #This is not run 


    t4 = time.time()

    print(f'I calculated second weights {t4-t3}') #This is not printed
```

The problem is whenever I'm running my code on PyCharm by clicking execute, the two transformations are applied successfully. But whenever I try to run with nohup, although on `top` command I can see parallel workers twice, but the second run never ends.

My question is how to run two subsequent transformations? I even tried to have the two transformations on the same wrapper function, but I encountered the same problem.

This is the output I get in nohup:

```
INFO: Pandarallel will run on 36 workers.
INFO: Pandarallel will use Memory file system to transfer data between the main process and workers.
init weights 135.39842891693115
INFO: Pandarallel will run on 36 workers.
INFO: Pandarallel will use Memory file system to transfer data between the main process and workers.
initial mapping preprocessing finished 2.7095065116882324
```

This is the output when I run it with PyCharm:

```
INFO: Pandarallel will run on 36 workers.
INFO: Pandarallel will use Memory file system to transfer data between the main process and workers.
init weights 143.19737672805786
INFO: Pandarallel will run on 36 workers.
INFO: Pandarallel will use Memory file system to transfer data between the main process and workers.
initial mapping preprocessing finished 2.6010115146636963
I calculated second weights 117.14078521728516
```

Once the parallel executors of the second function finish with the nohup case, there is only one memory-intensive job and nothing else happens

Thanks.

Comment: The environment or system resources available to the nohup process might differ from those in the interactive session in PyCharm, leading to different behavior.

Comment: Thanks. Given that I tried passing half the cores and it yet did not work with nohup, and that I want to run the job overnight, is there any workaround for that? Such as ensuring all resources from the first function are released after its completion.
The second function is even more lightweight than the first one.